# Is $\operatorname{Ker}\varphi$ free?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with identity and $M$ an $A$-module, then we have a canonical homomorphism $\varphi:A^{(M)}\to M$.

Is $\operatorname{Ker}\varphi$ free?

Comment: What does $\;A^{(M)}\;$ mean?

Comment: @DonAntonio: It is $\bigoplus\limits_{m \in M} A$ and the map sends each generator to element given in the index of the sum.

Comment: To make it more canonical, you can also view $A^{(M)}$ as $\{f: M \to A ~|~ f(m)=0 \text{ for all but finitely many } m\}$. Then you have a canonical map, which sends $f$ to $\sum\limits_{m \in M} f(m)m$. To make it even more canonical use the universal property of $A^{(M)}$ and note that the identity map $M \to M$ yields a map $A^{(M)} \to M$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is negative.

Here is an abstract argument: If the kernel would be always free, any commutative ring with unity would have global dimension $\leq 1$. For regular local notherian rings, the global dimension is equal to the Krull dimension and for singular local notherian rings, the global dimension is infinite. This is a theorem due to Serre.

In particular, there are situations where the kernel will not be free.

Answer (score 1):

An explicit counterexample is:

$$0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow  \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0$$

Where the first map is the multiplication by two and the second map is the one that associates to an element of $\mathbb{Z}/4 \mathbb{Z}$  its class in $\mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z}$. You can consider all these as $\mathbb{Z}/4 \mathbb{Z}$ modules and the first is not free for cardinality reasons.

Comment: Note that strictly speaking the map should be  $(\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z)^2 \to \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ (because $M$ has two elements in your example) with the second component mapping to zero. The kernel is $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$, clearly not free for the same reason you already mentioned. It has $8$ elements, but a free module has $4,16,64, \dotsc$ elements.

Comment: Anyway, props for giving precisely the simplest example available.

Comment: You're right, my fault: I didn't noticed that the OP asked for $A^{(M)}$ and not for a general free module.